# How to tag different styles of LARP?

Tags: discussion, tags, larp

I recently posted a question about larp on the main boards, as I was curious about some of the different styles of larp that existed. Mainly how they handled combat. I was expecting three answers, or styles (Along with more detail than I could give): Full-contact, low-contact and no contact, which would have been easier to tag. [Instead](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11861/what-different-styles-of-larp-combat-exist) the post contains a ton of different styles, and I don't know how to tag questions about larp.

This became an issue in one of my last larp questions, as it mattered that I was talking about a no-stab, felt-blow style larp. As opposed to a stab-safe, full-force larp.

How should we be tagging? Do we even want new tags? Or should we just stick with [larp](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/larp) and clarify in the question?

Answer (score 8):

I would clarify in the question given the current volume of LARP questions.

Comment: That said if people are using a specific LARP system, I see no harm in having a tag for it.

Answer (score 0):

If we have tags for different RPG systems, we should have tags for different LRP systems.  I see no problems in having `lrp-combat` as a tag and `lrp-combat-safe`, `lrp-combat-full` and the like...

I suggest we have them as `lrp-SYSTEM` to avoid confusion but that's just a suggestion.  Although this is probably not a good idea -- see comments.

Comment: Are they named similarly enough to existing systems that we would need to prefix them with `lrp-` or `larp-`?  If not, propose we leave off the prefix.  We don't have all that many characters in tags as it is.

Comment: @C.Ross: I have no idea.  If there is no confusion, then we can drop any pre or post fix.

Comment: I originally thought we could group them due to combat type, not system. That way combat questions such as my two weapon gighting one has some context.

Comment: Concur with @Pureferret: for combat LARPs, the combat style is probably more important than the system for many questions we get.  (Rules questions in combat LARPs are likely to be fewer and more system-specific.)  I think we're better with `larp-combat` and some variants, distinguished from non-combat LRPs which we should tag with something like `freeform`.  That said, do we actually have enough weapon questions to be worth tagging as opposed to just specifying in the question?